# Sorting by selecting the order of values ClickHouse

Tags: sql, database, clickhouse

MySQL has a sorting function that allows you to select the order of values ORDER BY FIELD()
ClickHouse does not have this function.
I have a similar request.:
`SELECT name FROM table WHERE id IN(5,3,7,8,11,14,54)`

I need the result to be returned in the order specified inside IN(). I can't find information anywhere on how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use **indexOf** keyword.

```
SELECT name
FROM table
WHERE id IN (5, 3, 7, 8, 11, 14, 54)
ORDER BY indexOf([5, 3, 7, 8, 11, 14, 54], id);
```

This gives you the result in the order specified in the **IN()** clause

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't work properly. arrayJoin does not accept more than one argument.

Comment: you can try to indexOf()   instead of arrayJoin(). Edit the answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
WITH [5, 3, 7, 8, 11, 14, 54] AS o
SELECT name 
FROM VALUES 
(
  'name UInt32'
, 3, 5, 7, 8, 11, 14, 54, 3, 5 --, ...
)
ORDER BY indexOf(o, name)
```

The result is:

```
|name|
|----|
|5   |
|5   |
|3   |
|3   |
|7   |
|8   |
|11  |
|14  |
|54  |
```